# Active link won't toggle on click. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a hamburger style menu icon that I want to animate to an "x" on click and then have the user click it again to make it go back. However, the icon will only animate all the way if you click and hold on it.

The scripts I use to try to toggle the active class don't work.

How do I solve this?

HTML:

```
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px; 
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle:active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle:active span:before, #nav-toggle:active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle:active span:before {
  transform:rotate(45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle:active span:after {
  transform:rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav-toggle').click( function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }//
  });
});
```

Also here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rf2qD/)

Comment: It should say `#nav-toggle.active` if you are adding the class with javascript. `:active` is a pseudo-selector.

Comment: it works OK here http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/rf2qD/4/, `:active` is a state selector, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
:active
```

with

```
.active
```

in your css

[Demo with your code](http://jsbin.com/lesotiqu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. However there are some points.
1) You forgot to include jQuery Library in your fiddle.
2) You have used `:active` pseudo element as your styling, where they should be `.active` representing `class` name

**HTML**

```
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px; 
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform:rotate(45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform:rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav-toggle').click( function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }//
});
});
```

Here is your updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rf2qD/5/